# using extjs jsonstore subdata in an combo field

Tags: extjs, combobox, jsonstore

following extjs3 problem:
i have an json store:

```
dbStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: '/?[action]=getFormData',
    storeId: 'formdata',
    fields: [{'database':['name', 'id'], 'parameter':['name','id']}],
    autoLoad: true
});
```

and i create an formpanel with following combo field:

```
{
xtype: 'combo',
name: 'database',
id: 'database',
store: ???,
fieldLabel: '',
valueField: 'id',
displayField: 'name',
emptyText: 'Select'
}
```

i want that combo field to use the 'database' fields 'name' and 'id', how to do that??

Comment: Your mapping information in the `field`-property looks some kind of weird. Can you show some sample data that's exposed by the given URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `root:'database'` to your store.

Comment: ...and set `fields` to `['name','id']`